# npm command not found - reactjs

Tags: reactjs, linux, window

I've got an error. I wanted to start npm create-react-app but it doesn't work.

I'm a window user. but i installed ubuntu and established linux environment.

so I opened it window terminal (wsl) and wrote npm create-react-app.

I don't know why it doesn't work..[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZXN3C.png)

Comment: Not sure what documentation you are using but it's `npx create-react-app` as documented [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/create-a-new-react-app.html#create-react-app)

Answer (score 1):

Please check you have node installed or not by running node -v, it should show you something like `v14.4.0` If not install nodejs from [here](https://nodejs.org/en/).

It will also install npm for you. To check that run npm -v. This will also return you a version, if not please [see this](https://www.npmjs.com/get-npm)

Once the above two steps are done, run this

```
npm install -g create-react-app
```

Once npm is installed then do

```
create-react-app <App Name>
```